# R loop for creating and using -csv

Tags: r, loops, output

I have a function output (from koRpus) of the form:
Total number of tokens: 887
Total number of types:  393

Measure of Textual Lexical Diversity
                MTLD: 142.66
   Number of factors: 6.22
         Factor size: 0.72
    SD tokens/factor: 41.55 (all factors)
                      38 (complete factors only)

And I want to make a loop for storing these results for 80 different documents. I have tried the following:

```
for (i in 1:length(infra$tableid)) {
  whypar <- paste(infra$whypar [infra[,1] ==i], collapse=" ")
wpi<- removeWords(whypar, stopwords("english"))

as.data.frame(wpi)
write.csv(data.frame(wpi), file= "wp.csv")

tagged.text <- tokenize("wp.csv", lang="en")

res.mtld <- MTLD(tagged.text)
  write.csv(data.frame(res.mtld),file="output.csv")
}
```

where infra is:

```
tableid 1, 2, 3, ... 80
whypar "I took part because xxx", "I believe that jshfdjk", "jhsadkjhd" ... (N=350)
```

---

Thanks for any help

Comment: And why isn't that working for you?  What is your desired result and what are you seeing now?  Also, if you can provide at least a minimal data set for `whypar` using `dput` it will be easier for us to help.

Comment: `dput(infra)` or `head(infra)` might help us to see your data structure

Comment: You cannot simply `data.frame` the S4 object created by MTLD. I am not well versed in text mining but perhaps you want one of the slots of this object. What part of the measure of textual lexical diversity are you interested in for each of your files. Use `str(res.mtld)` to examine your object and find the bits you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the parts of the MTLD object you are interested in first. From your question it seems like you are only interested in a subset of the object returned by MTLD, namely the MTLD score, number of factors the SD of tokens/factor and the SD for complete factors only. If you only want these results for each file you can just write one nice table as your output for all the files:

```
res <- data.frame( ID = numeric() , MTLD=numeric() , Factor_Size=numeric() , SD=numeric() , SD_Complete=numeric() )
for (i in 1:length(infra$tableid)) {
  whypar <- paste(infra$whypar [infra[,1] ==i], collapse=" ")
  wpi<- removeWords(whypar, stopwords("english"))

  wpi <- as.data.frame(wpi)
  write.csv(data.frame(wpi), file= "wp.csv")

  tagged.text <- tokenize("wp.csv", lang="en")

  res.mtld <- MTLD(tagged.text)
  mtld <- res.mtld@MTLD$MTLD
  fac.size <-  res.mtld@param$factor.size
  mtld.sd <- res.mtld@MTLD$lengths$sd
  mtld.sd.compl <- res.mtld@MTLD$lengths$sd.compl
  res <- rbind( res , c( infra$tableid[i] , mtld, fac.size , mtld.sd , mtld.sd.compl ) )
}
  write.csv( res , file="output.csv" )
```

I hope this helps, but check these are the results you want returned.

Comment: Thanks. It works exactly as expected... I was not familiar with slots.

Comment: @JorgePerez Since this worked exactly as expected, please can you press the green tick next to my answer so that this question can be removed from the unanswered questions stack. It's important to keep the site well curated. Thanking you in advance.